# MacOS - iOS Simulator: How to disable new toolbar on simulator? [Image Included]

Tags: ios, macos, screenshot, toolbar, simulator

[image]

Hey guys, 
Since the new iOS Simulator (Version 11.4 (921.9)), there is a toolbar at the top of the simulator. I simply want to disable it. It ruins my screenshots etc. Do you know any idea how to disable it?

Thank you.